# Attribute ImageFormatSettings.file_path doesn't exist

Tags: scripting, python, blender-internal-render-engine

I'm trying to make a script and I'm having trouble with this line:

```
bpy.data.scenes[0].render.file_format = 'PNG'
```

And it prints this error:

```
AttributeError: 'RenderSettings' object has no attribute 'fileformat'
```

Of course it's no big issue to click the mouse and set it, but I want to find out why it doesn't work. When I hover over the File Format menu in the render settings I see this:

```
bpy.data.scenes["Scene"] ... file_format
```

I noticed that there are a few other commands which show "..." in the attribute's "path". I checked out the docs, it doesn't say that file_format is deprecated. I'm using the latest version and Blender's default renderer.

Any idea why it doesn't work?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems that the path you tried to use only exists in a context for UI elements, from properties_render.py:

```
def draw(self, context):
    layout = self.layout

    rd = context.scene.render
    image_settings = rd.image_settings
    file_format = image_settings.file_format

    layout.prop(rd, "filepath", text="")
```

In a script you could use something like:

```
bpy.data.scenes[0].render.image_settings.file_format="PNG";
```